# Can HTML be considered styling?

Tags: html

The definition of styling is:

> "Design or make in a particular form"

Since HTML does style content, like we have `<i>`, `we can display content in lists`, `make content bold`, use heading by using `<h1>,<h2>...so on`. For me all of this does qualify as styling. So, Can HTML be considered styling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML has elements for both describing semantics and style. However HTML that mixes style and semantics often becomes difficult to maintain. For example, changing the style of certain elements consistently across a site might involve searching and replacing in multiple documents. CSS was introduced to solve this problem, giving a clear distinction between content and style and making it easy to apply site-wide styling.

While the styling elements in HTML still exist and can be used, it is preferable to use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

No. HTML is markup (structure). CSS is styling. The `<i>` is merely a markup tag, which is most commonly used for making text italic, but which can be declared to something completely different in your stylesheet. Same goes with list items. This is simply structure, which you may style in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Very subjective, but can you really call that styling, isn't it a bit far fetched? The only reason that it looks any different then plain text is because the browser add some default styling to various elements. This could easily be reset, leaving only the markup, without any styling.

The `i` tag was used for italic text early on, but it is still just a matter of styling. Twitter bootstrap uses it for a completely different purpose, for instance.

Comment: Changing <li> to list-style-type:none using CSS cannot be considered reset, isn't it? The display of the text in the form of lists or italic or bold is a styling in its own.

Comment: @AshwinSingh Well `display:none;` would hide it altogether, but you could easily apply the same CSS rules to an `li` as to an `i` element if you want to, making them look exactly the same. The look comes from the browser applying its own default CSS to the elements. The `<b>` is still just markup. You can easily reset it.

Comment: Sorry I meant list-style-type:none not display:none;